# SQL - create countings/sequence

Tags: sql

I am new at SQL. I would like to create 2 counts based on two variables, but I am not sure how to create this query on SQL.

Count 1 counts the number of transactions per customer (customer A one transaction on 01Jan count=1; customer A 2nd transaction on 01Jan count=2).

Count2 counts the sequence of visits of each customer at different days (customer A visit on 01Jan count=1; customer A visit on 02Jan count=2).

I would like to create 2 columns in the same table to show these counts.

Many thanks

Elisa

Comment: Don't tag products not involved. (MySQL and SQL Server and Oracle are different products, which one are you using.) This is to get the best attention!

Comment: (1) I am removing all the databases so you have the opportunity to add the *one* tag appropriate to the database you are actually using.  (2) You should edit the question and include sample data and desired results.

Comment: How do you count that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
  custid, 
  (select count(*) 
     from Transactions 
     where Transactions.custid = c.custid) Count1, 
  (select count(*) 
     from Visits 
     where Visits.custid = c.custid) Count2
  from Customer c;
```